# what does replace(/(^| )(\w)/g) means please any one describe it?

Tags: javascript

I was searching for  a solution to capitalize first letter of each word in a string and i got solution from stack overflow.

```
function convert_case(str) {
  var lower = str.toLowerCase();
  return lower.replace(/(^| )(\w)/g, function(x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

This code works. But i didn't understood what this code  means? Any one please describe it.

Comment: ...combined with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace of course.

Comment: E.g.: It matches either the beginning of the string or a space (`(^| )`) followed by a word character (`\w`), globally (`g`) through the string. `replace` calls the callback with the result of each match, and replaces the match with what the callback returns. Both of the capture groups in the regex are unnecessary, though; a single non-capturing group would be more appropriate: `/(?:^| )\w/g`